# Laravel migration error SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, artisan-migrate

I have a couple of Laravel migrations.

**1-create_countries_table`**

```
Schema::create('countries', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**2-create_cities_table**

```
Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->smallInteger('country_id');
    $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
});
```

When I use `php artisan migrate` , I see this error

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
 (SQL: alter table `cities` add constraint cities_country_id_foreign
 foreign key (`country_id`) references `countries` (`id`))

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't `refrences('id')` be `references('id')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();` instead of `$table->smallInteger('country_id');`

Comment: I do that but i have the same problem. I think the problem cause is laravel generate mysql query that dose not accept from mysql query syntax.

Comment: It should generate the right syntax if you selected the right driver in config files (mysql is the default I believe). Your error message seems to have a space after countries, double check to make sure its not the case in the migration.

Comment: I checked it out . and change refrence to references but steel i have problem.

Comment: Did you figure it out? what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

solution for this problem.
add to app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot(){
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

In the laravel when use `$table->increments('id');` Laravel create a    int(10) field.
to connect a field to an id as foregin key it must be int(10). for make a foreign key int 10 we muste use this code:

```
$table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
```

if dont use `unsigned();` method, a field will create by int(11) type and isn't mach to int(10)